# Grep but very literal

Tags: unix, text, grep

This question might have been asked a million times before, but did’t see my exaxt case.

Suppose a text file contains:

```
a
ab
bac
```

Now I want to grep on ‘a’ and have a hit only on the 1st line. After the ‘a’ there’s always a [tab] character.

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks!

Ronald

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
head -1 *.txt | grep -P "a\t"
```

head will give you specified amount of lines of each file (all txt files in my example) ,  grep -P use the regular expressions as defined by perl (perl has \t as tab)